# Why does this float operation in C++ and Java give different results?

Tags: java, c++

I just came across [this](http://floating-point-gui.de/) website and tried doing that in Java and C++. Why writing the following in Java gives 0.30000000000000004

```
double x = 0.1 + 0.2;
System.out.print(x);
```

Whereas writing the following in C++ gives 0.3?

```
double x = 0.1 + 0.2;
cout<<x;
```

Comment: In C++, print with higher precision: `cout << setprecision(15) << x`. I predict the result is the same, it just gets printed with more digits by default in Java.

Comment: read about `print` and `cout` formatting options

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera Do you know what happens 'actually'?

Comment: By default, the C++ output stream operator prints floating values with six digits. If those six digits have trailing zeros after the decimal point, the zeros will be removed.

Comment: @MattAdams Thanks Matt! Got it! So, what we gotta do with C++ is `std::cout<<std::setprecision(17)<<std::fixed<<x;` to get the same output. They put it on hold as 'too broad'! :D

Comment: Becasue Java is 10^16 times more accurate than C ;-)

Comment: [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) may be helpful

Comment: Hi @AndrewBarber! As you can see the answer is really simple. I guess you can reopen this question. Anyway my doubt is clarified. Thanks!

Comment: @Shravan Reopened it for ya.

Answer (score 4):

There is no guarantee from the C++ standard that [IEEE 754 floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) is used, so the result is actually implementation defined.  However, most implementations will do it.

In Java, `float` and `double` [are defined to be IEEE 754 floating point types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3).  In addition, you can add the [`strictfp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.4) modifier to a class or method declaration to require strict IEEE 754 floating point arithmetic be used even for intermediary results.

When dealing with floating point numbers, in case of doubt, it is often useful to look at the actual bit representation.

```c++
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

int
main()
{
  static_assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(uint64_t), "wrong bit sizes");
  const double x = 0.1 + 0.2;
  const uint64_t bits = *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t *>(&x);
  printf("C++:  0x%016lX\n", bits);
  return 0;
}
```

```java
public final class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final double x = 0.1 + 0.2;
        final long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(x);
        System.out.printf("Java: 0x%016X\n", bits);
    }
}
```

When I execute both programs on my computer (GNU/Linux with GCC and OpenJDK), the output is

```
C++:  0x3FD3333333333334
Java: 0x3FD3333333333334
```

which shows that both yield the exact same result.  However, a portable program should not rely on this.

Answer (score 2):

In IEEE floating point representation, neither 0.1 nor 0.2 (nor 0.3) are exact values. Only negative power of 2 and their combinations would be (0.5, 0.25, 0.75 for example ...).

So the differences that you see are only differences in the default output formatting as stated by Matt Adams.

Answer (score 0):

Decide your precision level, and specifically set that for the output stream, that should show same